# open atrium file attachments access permissions across spaces

Tags: users, files, distributions

Open Atrium 2. fully updated, successfully running without error messages.

I have a setup where I am using 2 spaces *All Users* (authenticated + space membership) and *Directors* (authenticated plus access to this space and All Staff space). Members may be promoted or demoted at various times due to their responsibilities.

All documents have good access control when anonymous users access the site. Nodes are not visible unless the viewer is logged in and is a member of the space that holds the node. All attachments are visible to space members when they open the node.

If a member of group *All Staff* guesses the url of an attachment in a node created in *Directors*,  my question is how to restrict/inherit permissions for attachments and media within a node? It is probably right in front of me but I am must have overlooked it.

thanks in advance,
Simon